# Fetching data from snowflake table and insert JSON values to VARIANT column in another snowflake table

Tags: json, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to fetch data from a Snowflake table Employee and insert values to VARIANT column of another snowflake table in JSON format.

| EMP_ID | EMP_NAME | SALARY | POSITION |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ABC | 100 | ENGINEER |
| 2 | DEF | 300 | MANAGER |
| 3 | GHI | 500 | DIRECTOR |

Expected JSON format:

```
{
"EMP_ID":"1",
"EMP_NAME":"ABC",
"SALARY":"100",
"POSITION":"ENGINEER"
}
{
"EMP_ID":"2",
"EMP_NAME":"DEF",
"SALARY":"300",
"POSITION":"MANAGER"
}
{
"EMP_ID":"3",
"EMP_NAME":"GHI",
"SALARY":"500",
"POSITION":"DIRECTOR"
}
```

The above JSON formatted data should be loaded to a table EMP_JSON(load_data VARIANT, load_date TIMESTAMP_LTZ).

I tried hardcoding the values. But I would like to fetch the values dynamically.

```
INSERT INTO EMP_JSON
SELECT PARSE_JSON('{"EMP_ID":"1", "EMP_NAME":"ABC", "SALARY":"100", "POSITION":"ENGINEER"}'), CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS LOAD_DATE ;
```

Could you please tell me how to load such JSON value to a variant column in Snowflake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it's mentioned, you can use **object_construct** to generate JSON object. The important point is, you can call object_construct with * parameter to read all columns dynamically (you don't need to specify columns) and produce the JSON:

```
create table emp( EMP_ID number, EMP_NAME varchar, SALARY number, POSITION varchar );
INSERT INTO emp(EMP_ID,EMP_NAME,SALARY,POSITION) VALUES (1,'ABC',100,'ENGINEER');
INSERT INTO emp(EMP_ID,EMP_NAME,SALARY,POSITION) VALUES (2,'DEF',300,'MANAGER');
INSERT INTO emp(EMP_ID,EMP_NAME,SALARY,POSITION) VALUES (3,'GHI',500,'DIRECTOR');

create table EMP_JSON(load_data VARIANT, load_date TIMESTAMP_LTZ);

insert into EMP_JSON select object_construct(*), current_timestamp from emp;

select * from EMP_JSON;
```

If you want to select specific columns:

```
insert into EMP_JSON select select object_construct('EMP_ID',EMP_ID, 'EMP_NAME', EMP_NAME), current_timestamp from emp;
```

OBJECT_CONSTRUCT https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/object_construct.html

Comment: Thank you ! What if i want to select specific columns from the table?

Comment: Added to my response

Comment: If there is a table with 100 columns, and I would like to eliminate 3 columns from the table while using object_construct, is there any way we can eliminate three columns from the selection? Or would it require explicit selection of 97 other columns?

Comment: Yes it's possible, please check OBJECT_DELETE  https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/object_delete.html#object-delete

Comment: Wow ! Thank you so much. Much appreciated :)

Comment: Using object_construct(*) is resulting me in order that is not the same as the table columns order. I believe the keys are getting sorted in alphabetical order. How do we maintain order of the keys?

Answer (score 1):

@vvazza, use the object_construct function to select the data from table and it returns a JSON object and that can go to variant column.

Comment: Thank you ! What if i want to select specific columns from the table?

Comment: If there is a table with 100 columns, and I would like to eliminate 3 columns from the table while using object_construct, is there any way we can eliminate three columns from the selection? Or would it require explicit selection of 97 other columns?

Comment: You can write a stored procedure which can describe the table and you can use result_scan table function to get the column names as table structure and then take input for the columns which need to be eliminated and process it to generate it dynamically. If time permits, I could share the code sample.

Comment: That'd be really helpful :) Could you please share it? :)